# States on a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I know that  if $A$ is a non-zero and unital $C^*$-algebra then $S(A)$ (the set of states on it) is weak${}^*$ compact.

My problem is:

> Does the same hold if $A$ is not unital?

Comment: It means Weak* compact

Comment: I am pretty sure that $A$ being unital is crucial. What non-unital $C^*$-algebras do you know?

Comment: Let $A$ be unital and ‎‎$‎‎f_{‎\alpha‎} ‎\subseteq S(A)‎$ ‎such ‎that ‎‎‎$‎‎‎‎f_{‎\alpha‎} ‎‎\overrightarrow{weak^*} f‎‎‎‎‎‎$ ‎then ‎we ‎have‎‎
‎‎‎$‎‎‎‎f_{‎\alpha‎}(1) ‎‎‎\longrightarrow‎ f(1)‎‎‎‎‎‎$.thus we have‎
‎$1=‎‎‎‎\|‎ f_{‎\alpha‎} ‎‎\|‎=f_{‎\alpha‎}(1)=f(1)=‎\| f‎\|‎‎‎‎$‎
‎

Comment: I don't understand your answer to my comment. I was asking for what examples of non-unital $C^*$-algebras you know. It looks like you are arguing that the state space in a unital $C^*$algebra is closed.

Comment: I am looking for non unital c star algebra that

Comment: S(A) is not closed

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$, and let $\varphi_n\in S(A)$ be given by $$\varphi_n(g)=g(n).$$
Then $\varphi_n\to0$ pointwise, and so $S(A)$ is not closed.

With a similar idea: you can take $A=K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ and, with $\{e_n\}$ the canonical basis,
$$
\varphi_n(x)=\langle xe_n,e_n\rangle.
$$